# comparison between angularjs and jsrender

Tags: angularjs, jsrender

My new requirement is to use jsrender to build a grid (means table), however i used to build a table using angularjs. Could anyone suggest me, which one will faster and customisable grid(table)?

Comment: please edit your question with the proper code. This question is not at all clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need rendering, JsRender is much more light-weight, and will be faster.

If you want full and rich interactivity, with dynamic behavior such as sorting or adding rows), you will need either AngularJS or JsViews.

JsViews is JsRender plus interactivity and dynamic data-binding: [www.jsviews.com/#jsviews](http://www.jsviews.com/#jsviews).

Here is [an example](https://jsfiddle.net/BorisMoore/ejua24ry/) with of a sortable table with JsViews.

```
<table>
  <tbody><tr>
    {^{for list.cols ~list=list}}...{{/for}}
    <td></td>
  </tr></tbody>
  <tbody>
    {^{forPlus list.rows ^sortby=list.sortby ^reverseSort=list.reverseSort ~list=list}}
      <tr>...</tr>
    {{/forPlus}}
    ...
  </tbody>
</table>
```